# How to get font size between two ranges in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to get the font size between two ranges.

```
$base-font: 1px;

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .th-#{i} {
    font-size: $base-font + $i +  px;
  }
}
```

When I am using class `.th-30`, I am not getting a font size of `30px`.

Comment: Your code produces values such as `font-size: 2pxpx;`. Don't append the `px`;

Comment: @Turnip I tried by removing ```px``` . But that didnt helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the `$base-font` variable altogether. Also, you're missing a dollar sign in the selector:

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .th-#{$i} {
    font-size: $i +  px;
  }
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6fn9u2mb/)

Comment: answering the same answer, feel sad ;(

Comment: We answered at the same time @NishargShah

Answer (score 2):

Here are some changes you need to do.

There is no need for `$base-font` here

```
$base-font: 1px;

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .th-#{$i} {
    font-size: #{$i}px;
  }
}
```